# Why my Robotframework always running on Firefox

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

im trying to create test cases in robotframework using chrome as the browser but it didnt work. Everytime i run the code it automatically open on Firefox

I have tried to using chrome as variable but it didnt work

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Browser} Chrome
${URL}  https://www.google.co.id



*** Test Cases ***
Test case Register Positive
    Open Browser$   {URL} ${Browser}
    Close Browser
```

Comment: Are you getting errors when you run? When I run your code I get the error `Invalid variable name '${browser} chrome'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the actual code you are running? You have only one space between `${URL}` and `${Browser}`, thus they are becoming one value. 
Put at least 2 spaces between them.